# String assignments and output

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
String str1 = new String("Hello");
String str2 = str1;
String str3 = new String(str1);
String str4 = str3;
str4 += " World ";
if (str3==str4)
     System.out.println(“one”);
if (str3.equals(str4))
     System.out.println(“two”);
if (str1==str2)
     System.out.println(“three”); 
if (str3.equals(str2))
     System.out.println(“four”);
```

The output is : Three and Four

I don't get it.. we just did str3 == str4 . how can they NOT refer to the same object..?
str3 == str4 seem to be false and I dont get why. In addition, the str3.equals(str4) also return false but I guess that has something to do with the first thing I dont get.

Would love to get an explanation.

Comment: this is a duplicate, please browse the site for similar questions . :)

Comment: duplicate..? how come? I did look for similar questions.

Comment: this one..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?           That doesnt answer my question.

Comment: `str4 += " World ";` changes the value of `str4` - it's as simple as that. After that statement, `str4` refers to a string with contents `Hello World ` but `str3` still refers to a string with contents `Hello`. So they're not only distinct string objects, but objects with different contents.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The OP clearly knows how to compare strings, but the confusion comes from misunderstanding of how object references work in conjunction with string immutability.

Comment: This question is not about comparison but about the `+=` operator.

Comment: Because a `String` is immutable, the `+=` operator creates a new instance and assignes it to `str4`. Therefore `str4` is not equal `str3`.

Comment: How would you get as you had appended str4 += " World "; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a `String` is immutable, the `+=` operator creates a new instance and assignes it to `str4`. Therefore `str4` is not equal `str3`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what happens: `str3` and `str4` start off referencing the same object. However, since Java `String` is immutable and thus cannot be modified in-place, this line

```
str4 += " World ";
```

results in assigning `str4` a reference to a brand-new object. That is why the subsequent comparison `str3==str4` fails.